# Passing a text field value on a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, event-handling

Here is the code that contains the text field and the button. I want to call the "apiFetcher" function with the value of the text field. I commented out the onblur function in the text field. That worked perfectly fine. Any suggestions to fix this issue.

```
<Autocomplete
    id="free-solo-2-demo"
    disableClearable
    options={Cities.map((option) => option.name)} 
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <div
      >
      <TextField
        id="standard-basic" 
        {...params}
        label="city"
        margin="normal"
        InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: 'search' }}
        // onBlur={apiFtecher}
      />
      
  </div>
    )}
  />
  </Grid>
  <Grid className={classes.seIcon} item xs={1}>
    <div onClick={apiFtecher}>
        <IconButton>
            <SearchIcon/>
        </IconButton>
    </div>
  </Grid>
```

Here is the apiFetcher function

```
 const apiFtecher = e => {
  setcity(e.target.value);
  console.log(city);
 }
```

Comment: what is the problem here? you cannot call the `apiFetcher` `onclick`?

Comment: and is the `TextField` the material ui component?

Comment: @alisasani yes.i want to pass the text field value to the function on click

Comment: OnBlur set the input value to local state and onClick of the div, access the state value for fetching the result.

Comment: @SarunUK okay i'll try that and let you know if it works

Comment: @aravinda I have created a code base. It might help you - https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-pare-zv292?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SarunUK thank you for giving me the idea mate. I did use another function to change the city and bind it to the buttons on-click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i did

```
const [town,settown]=useState("");

function APIsetter(){
       return(
         setcity(town)
       )
     }
```

And then bind the APIsetter to onclick function of the button.And it worked